# QPixmap copy speed

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

Compositing multiple images into one using Qt's QPixmap as the storage:

```
QPainter painter(&destinationPixmap);
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, sourcePixmap);
```

This seems to be quite slow (2-10ms for a maximised window on typical monitor) - any way to do it quicker without changing to completely different technology?

Comment: Do you know this?: [Qt Graphics and Performance – An Overview](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/12/16/qt-graphics-and-performance-an-overview/). Depending on how the images are composited, _may be_, `QImage` may provide benefit with conversion to `QPixmap` as late as possible. Hard to say without more details.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, probably `omp parallel` could help ?

Comment: "Qt Graphics and Performance" mentions that QPixmaps are a pool of OpenGL Frame Buffer Objects, which explains why they're faster than CPU-based QImage.

Answer (score 0):

Qt documentation [says](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#details):

> QImage is designed and optimized for I/O, and for **direct pixel access and manipulation**, while QPixmap is designed and optimized for **showing images on screen**.

So the proper way is to complete all composition manipulations with QImages and then, if you are going to display/repaint the result multiple times, it would be better to convert a resulting QImage to a QPixmap before it rendered.

Comment: Using QImage instead of QPixmap increased the time taken by a factor of 10.

Comment: @OJW Increases the time taken for what?

Comment: Total time to combine a stack of images using the method above, takes much longer if the images are stored in QImage instead of QPixmap.  (using QPainter::drawImage and QPainter::drawPixmap respectively)

Comment: @OJW "2-10ms for a maximised window" - does it mean that a displaying is slow, not a composing?

Comment: 2-10ms measurement doesn't include displaying the final image on screen.